# Ansible: check, do and check again

Tags: shell, ansible

Is there a compact way of checking whether something is installed, installing it if necessary and then checking again?  At the moment I have this verbose mess:

```
  - name: check whether X is installed.
    shell: is_installed >/dev/null || echo nope
    register: thing_is_installed
  - name: install something
    shell: install_thing
    when: thing_is_installed=="nope"
  - name: check that the install succeeded
    shell: is_installed
```

for arbitrary functions `install_thing` and `is_installed`?  The big problem is that is_installed occurs twice, so there is a risk that someone will modify the one function call but not the other, on account of carelessness, oversight or any number of other reasons.  Shell is just an example.  You may recognise the pattern - it is the core building block of idenpotent build functions.  `is_installed` defines the desired state and `install_thing` defines how to get to the desired state.  I expect that there is a form that looks like this, I just can't find it:

```
- name: Install boondoggle
  shell:
    check: is_installed
    install: install_thing
```

Or this, which has the advantage that it can be used with any number of tests, not just shell:

```
- name: Install bongle
  check:
    shell: is_installed
  install:
    shell: install_thing
```

Comment: The Markdown engine here isn't GitHub-flavored -- triple-quotes don't start multi-line code blocks. Use the `{}` button to add four-space indents for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy

Comment: BTW -- what are the exit status values of your command/script? In an ideal world, you'd have distinct values for "it's already done", "it needs to be done", "I did it successfully", "tried and failed", etc.

Comment: The thing is that an install script can return 0 yet have failed.  The only really reliable route is to re-run the test.  But I do regard any non-zero exit code to be fatal unless it's the check running the first time round, in which case it knows that it needs to run th einstaller.

Comment: I suggest -- strongly -- that you fix that. Even if you fix that by having a wrapper that simply retests before setting exit status.

Comment: I also tend to take the approach of having the commands I call from ansible, rather than the ansible code itself, do the work of being idempotent. That's not ideal, but, well, *ansible* isn't ideal; if it were Chef, we'd have a more powerful toolkit to work with.

Comment: But that is exactly the point.  I have two commands, an "am I in this state" command and a "put me in this state" command.  The point of tool such as ansible is to get me into said sate efficiently and to provide visibility on whether I am in that state.  Were I to take the "am I in this state" function and add it to the "put me in this state" function I would be back to having duplication and the potential that the two tests diverge.

Comment: And if your "put me in this state" command can't correctly report whether it was successful, it's buggy. Fix it. Maybe "fix it" just means making it `install_thing && is_installed`, but it's still a fix.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of having `is_installed` be separate, if you don't have a noop mode?

Comment: If "is installed" says yes the first time round the "install" is skipped, so there is a no-op mode.  In the first code chunk, if the thing is installed, the variable "thing_is_installed" is blank so the "when" skips the installation.

Comment: That's not a "noop mode" in the sense of what other tools (Puppet &c) provide. Generally speaking, a proper noop mode is one where you make no changes **even if you're not in your desired state**, thus allowing the orchestration system to be asked what it *would* do if it were being run in a real (non-noop) mode.

Comment: Can you describe puppy's noop?

Comment: http://nrvale0.github.io/posts/2014/04/the-basics-of-puppet-noop/ is the first thing that googled up and looks accurate at a glance. One caveat re: such accuracy -- it's *not* a feature unique to puppet.

Comment: (...and, to be clear, I don't like Puppet much either -- back when I was using it, I had a different set of places where I was writing shims and scripts to do things a more flexible tool could have accommodated natively, but there was still far too much of that; as awful a language as Ruby is, I find myself a Chef fan nonetheless, simply by virtue of being a tool that has the capabilities one needs when tackling hard problems built in rather than bolted on).

Comment: I have a ton of shell script installers and a small function that does `check || install && check`.  I am hoping that there is some mainstream structure that I can switch to so that I don't have to write all my own checks for "is x in state y".  On the upside, my installers are fast compared with others I have encountered.  Not sure why.  Still, I don't want to be stuck as the only maintainer.  https://github.com/bitdivine/bashops-install

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of pre-existing shell scripts that you want to use, then your options are limited. Especially if the parameters and return values are inconsistent.

Using the shell module in Ansible is a last resort. Sometimes you have to use it, but consider modules like '[package](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html)' and '[pip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html)' first. Also check [ansible-galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) for complete roles that may do what you need. It's easy to try and do it all, but sometimes the work has already been done by others and even if it's only 50% of what you need. That's still time saved.

With the shell option, there is a '[creates](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html)' option. This checks for the existance of a file known to be created by the shell script and can be used instead of 'check' -> 'do' -> 'check' in some circumstances.  The documentation also has further detail on useful [test strategies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/test_strategies.html). Obviously it all depends on your particular needs.

Another alternative if your shell scripts are uniform is to [write your own](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html) wrapper module for them. With a little python knowledge this is very easy to do. Once again, it's possible to find [open source examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core) and work from one which is similar to what you need rather than start from scratch. The internal process of the module will still need to do check -> fix -> check, but within the Ansible playbooks, the code will be very neat and avoid repatition.

Comment: The return values are consistent for the tests, inconsistent for the installers.  The shell script is well structured in that they are lots of pairs of functions, where one function is an "is it in the desired state" function and the second is a "put it in the desired state" function.  As such, the logical steps are very clean.  The question is how to express the same logic in Ansible.

Comment: I might go for the own module.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel if such a module already exists though.

Comment: I also note some philosophical differences between my scripts and ansible's builtin modules.  E.g. my apt installer the decision on whether to update apt is expressed in terms of acceptable cache age, which is an expression of state.  In ansible, update cache is a boolean which is imperative.  That seems weird.

Comment: For sure, there will be differences between tools. In this case, Ansible does support `cache_valid_time` as an option to the [apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html). This can be used instead of the more blunt `update_cache` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Absent a noop mode (that is, a mode in which you report failure but **don't** follow through with any installation in the event that you're not yet in your desired state), you might as well combine the two. I tend to use a pattern akin to the following:

```
  - name: "enforce-foo"
    command: /path/to/enforce-foo-script
    register: enforce_foo
    failed_when: "(enforce_foo.rc != 0) and (enforce_foo.rc != 2)"
    changed_when: "enforce_foo.rc != 2"
```

...here, we're using exit status 0 to indicate that we exited without needing to do anything, and exit status 2 to indicate that we made changes.

Comment: That is interesting but I am concerned that most existing functions don't adhere to the 0/1/2 exit codes so basically all the work of checking that the desired state corresponds to reality is pushed out to the shell.  So.. why use ansible?

Comment: You're talking to someone who $@#% hates ansible (and Puppet, and SaltStack, and cfengine), so don't look to me for that answer. I wish I could love Pallet, being that its implementation language is one I'm fond of, but alas, it ends up in the "not up to the job" category as well.

Comment: But you've clearly been around the block so I appreciate your input!

Comment: A small update: It looks as if do-until loops can do check-install-check in the (very limited) cases where the check can be done just in a simple python jenja clause.  I made a module that lets tasks be declared as a list of scripts to check state and a list of scripts to "make it so".  In order to leverage everything that Ansible has to offer I need to let the check and test be any list of ansible tasks, not just shell scripts.  I'm getting there!  https://github.com/bitdivine/ansible-bashops